# Access file using dash upload

Tags: plotly-dash

I am wanting to permit the user to select a file (fmu - just think of it as a zipped folder) to upload and then send that file to a function for use.

- The function (FUNC) to which the file is being sent requires a string input specifying the file location. It will not accept a bytes-like object or anything else.
- The upload component, as far as I understand, for security purposes does not return a file path though it does have a filename. Providing this file name to FUNC does not work.

Question:

How can one properly load a file that does not support the decode-style methods that would normally be used (i.e., csv, xlsx, txt, etc.)?
For example, if the "Upload" component literally brings the file into some sort of memory location, is there a way to get the string filepath to the uploaded location and thereby allow FUNC to access the uploaded file?

Much obliged for any help one may provide. Below is the code I am currently using which fails to access the file in an acceptable format.

```
from pyfmi import load_fmu

from dash import Dash, dcc, html, dash_table, Input, Output, State, callback
import base64
import io
import datetime                  

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-fmu',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag & Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '10%',
            'height': '40px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-fmu-upload'),
])
     
def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)

    try:
        if 'fmu' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a FMU file
            # model = load_fmu(io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8'))) # fails
            # model = load_fmu(io.BytesIO(decoded)) # fails
            model = load_fmu(filename) # fails
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])

    return html.Div([
        # For debugging, display the raw contents provided by the web browser
        html.Div('Raw Content'),
        html.Pre(contents[0:200] + '...', style={
            'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap',
            'wordBreak': 'break-all'
        })
    ])

@callback(Output('output-fmu-upload', 'children'),
              Input('upload-fmu', 'contents'),
              State('upload-fmu', 'filename'),
              State('upload-fmu', 'last_modified'))
def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
        children = [
            parse_contents(c, n, d) for c, n, d in
            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]
        return children

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to use the experimental(?) [dash_uploader](https://github.com/np-8/dash-uploader) package.

- This is the component call

```
def get_upload_component(id):
    return du.Upload(
        id=id,
        max_file_size=1800,
        filetypes=['fmu'],
        upload_id=uuid.uuid1(),
        cancel_button=True,
    )
```

- This is the callback function where I am returning a string of the full filepath of the uploaded fmu.

```
@du.callback(
    output=Output('upload-fmu-output',component_property='children'),
    id='upload-fmu',
)
def upload_fmu_callback(status: du.UploadStatus):
    list_files = [str(x) for x in status.uploaded_files]
    if list_files is None:
        filename = ''
    else:
        filename = list_files[0]  
    return filename
```

- Here is then a callback and function loading the fmu

```
def parse_fmu(filename):
    try:
        if 'fmu' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a FMU file
            model = load_fmu(filename)
            return model
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])

@app.callback(
    Output('variables-calibrate', component_property='options'),
    Output('variables-metric', component_property='options'),
    Input('upload-fmu-output', component_property='children')
    )
def update_variables_selection(filename):

    if '.fmu' in filename:
        model = parse_fmu(filename)
        variable_names = list(model.get_model_variables())
    else:
        variable_names = []
    return variable_names, variable_names
```